# Are questions about learning methods on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, scope

I want to ask the community certain questions about pedagogy for online learning. For instance, when practicing listening activities for journalists, whether ELL knows how we can both listen to the same thing at the same time. If this is not on topic, where should it be asked?

Comment: This was discussed a long time ago here : [Is pedagogy off-topic?](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/29) but it wouldn't hurt to talk about it again to make sure the community still feels the same way about it.

Comment: Another thing that we should keep in mind is that [languagelearning.se] is currently in public beta. After reading over the discussion I linked a while ago, I think that we should accept pedagogy questions on English, but if we encounter questions about language learning in general, we might want to make the author aware of the new site. I don't know that I would consider those off-topic exactly though - it would depend on the question.